# Particular bash bc usage not storing result in variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, bc

Unfortunately this result in a empty variable, and bc command print its result to terminal anyway while trying to attribute to aux

```
aux=&(bc -l <<< "scale = 5; c(${arguments[0]}*$constant)")
echo "$aux"
```

how can I store this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, you should use `$(...)` to store output of a command, not `&(...)`.

```
aux=&(...)
```

is interpreted as `aux=` and `(...)` connected by `&`, i.e. it clears `$aux` in the background, and runs the `bc` in a subshell.